# setting a task using anacron (is this syntax correct?)

Tags: debian, syntax-error, backup, task, scheduled-tasks

Here's my OS information:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.2 (jessie)
Release:    8.2
Codename:   jessie
```

I am trying to backup my gmail using gmvault on a daily basis. What I usually do in terminal is go to:

```
/home/myusername/Programs/gmvault-1.9/bin
```

and then run the following command:

```
./gmvault sync myemail@gmail.com -t quick –no-compression
```

It works just fine that way. However, to automate it, what I tried was going to:

```
/etc
```

I then ran the following command to edit what I think is the relevant file:

```
sudo gedit anacrontab
```

This is what appears including the line I added, which is is the very last one:

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root

# These replace cron's entries
1   5   cron.daily  run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7   10  cron.weekly run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly    15  cron.monthly    run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly
1   7   gmv ./gmvault sync myemail@gmail.com -t quick –no-compression /home/myusername/Programs/gmvault-1.9/bin
```

As you can see, I want this task to run once a day, seven minutes after startup, called it "gmv," then listed the command along with the location. However, while editing, I got a whole bunch of errors in terminal, which are mainly repeats of the following two:

```
(gedit:8833): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

** (gedit:8833): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-language not supported
```

Can someone please help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When calling GUI programs from the command line as root, use `gksudo`.  For example:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/anacrontab
```

That eliminates those messages you were seeing.

Although those messages state there was an error, it's worthwhile to note that they are, in fact, warning messages.  As such you should still be able to save the document.

For more info you can take a look at the man pages: `man 1 gksudo`